# Counting number of appearances from two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got two columns as below from the table - **matches**. I want to find the count of appearances for each umpire (irrespective of whether he's umpire1 or umpire2). Do note that there's no duplicate data as the same pair of umpires can appear for multiple matches.

```
|----------|----------|
| umpire1  | umpire2  |
|----------|----------|
| Rauf     | Koertzen |
| Benson   | Harper   | 
| Koertzen | Harper   |
| Harper   | Rauf     |
| Rauf     | Benson   |
| Benson   | Koertzen |
| Rauf     | Koertzen |
| Rauf     | Harper   |
| Bowden   | Koertzen |
|----------|----------|
```

I want my output to be in this format:

```
|----------|-----------|
|  umpire  |appearances|
|----------|-----------|
| Benson   |     3     |
| Bowden   |     1     | 
| Harper   |     4     |
| Koertzen |     5     |
| Rauf     |     5     |
|----------|-----------|
```

I'm able to find the appearances for each umpire separately but only from one column at a time. For instance,

```
SELECT umpire1, COUNT(umpire1) FROM matches
GROUP BY umpire1
```

the above gives me count of appearances for only umpire1 column. Similarly, I can get count of appearances for umpire2 column. But I want an aggregated column with umpires and their respective counts of appearances from both the columns. I tried using "UNION" and "UNION ALL" commands, but they seem to just append the results from both the columns.

Comment: You would need to wrap a union query in a main query which counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5PpTXRZY4FcAzUUG2HLrCw/2).

```
select
    umpire,
    sum(app) as appearances 
from
(
  select
    umpire1 as umpire,
    count(umpire1) as app
from umpires
group by
    umpire1

union all

select
    umpire2 as umpire,
    count(umpire2) as app
from umpires
group by
    umpire2
) val
group by
    umpire
```

Output:

```
*----------------------*
|umpire |  appearances |
*----------------------*
|Benson     3          |
|Bowden     1          |
|Harper     4          |
|Koertzen   5          |
|Rauf       5          |
*----------------------*
```